# How do I build sqlcipher?

Tags: c, sqlite, mingw, linker-errors

First, I completed the build using `mingw` and created the `sqlcipher.exe` file.
By the way, there was a warning during the build.
So, I doubt if I built it properly.

Warning content:

```
$ make
./libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC gcc -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -I/c/opensslbuild32/include /c/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll -L/c/sqlcipher/ -static-libgcc -DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1 -I. -I/c/sqlcipher/src -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/rtree -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/icu -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/fts3 -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/async -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/session -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DBUILD_sqlite -DNDEBUG  -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1    -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=1 -c sqlite3.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -I/c/opensslbuild32/include /c/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll -L/c/sqlcipher/ -static-libgcc -DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1 -I. -I/c/sqlcipher/src -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/rtree -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/icu -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/fts3 -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/async -I/c/sqlcipher/ext/session -D_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H -DBUILD_sqlite -DNDEBUG -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=1 -c sqlite3.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/sqlite3.o
sqlite3.c: In function 'sqlcipher_cipher_profile':
sqlite3.c:21289:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fopen_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 if(fopen_s(&f, destination, "a") != 0){
    ^~~~~~~
gcc.exe: warning: c:/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll: linker input file because linking not done
```

especially,I think the sentence is a problem.

Can I ignore the warning?
I am worried that the `openssl` library is properly linked and built.
Was it a good build?

Comment: The linker misses the implementation of `fopen_s()` called in file sqlite3.c at line 21289. So no, this build failed.

Comment: You say "I am worried that the `openssl` library *is* ...".  Do you mean "*is not*"?

Comment: I think I do not seem to be linked properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I ignore the warning?

No, you cannot.

The linker misses the implementation of `fopen_s()` called in file sqlite3.c at line 21289:

```
sqlite3.c:21289:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fopen_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 if(fopen_s(&f, destination, "a") != 0){
    ^~~~~~~
```

So no again, this build for `libeay32.dll` failed.

Comment: An executable cannot be built with a linker error, right? Is it possibly an old executable?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: err what? Which executable?

Comment: Thank you for answer.
May I know what the problem is?

Comment: OP: "First, I completed the build using `mingw` and created the `sqlcipher.exe` file."

Comment: @FiddlingBits: As I wrote: it's the build for a DDL that is failing.

Comment: @hoyo: As I wrote: "*The linker misses the implementation of `fopen_s()` called in file sqlite3.c at line 21289*". This function's implementation should be available either in a library or inside any of the sources belonging to the DLL.

Comment: [`fopen_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) should come with the [MSC run-time libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx).

Comment: `/c/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll ` is missing an option, isn't?  Should use `-l`?

Comment: What is the MSC runtime library ..?
I built it by referring to the site
http://www.jerryrw.com/howtocompile.php

Comment: I entered it in migw as follows:
/ Configure --with-crypto-lib = none --disable-tcl CFLAGS = "- DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL -I / c / opensslbuild32 / include /c/sqlcipher/libeay32.dll -L /c/sqlcipher/static -libgcc "LDFLAGS =" - leay32 "

Comment: You better turn to the author of this "how to compile" page.

Comment: Okay..Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.